# CSS3 Animation won't work in Opera and Firefox, but works in Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, firefox, animation, opera, vendor-prefix

Please help me, I can't see bug. I tryed everything. Thanks people. You can see my code on this link.

http://jsfiddle.net/astrogastro/dFZgn/

```
   #sun{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: yellow;
    background-image: url('img/sunmap.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size:1000px;
    animation-name:rotateSun;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function:linear;
    -o-animation-name:rotateSun;
    -o-animation-duration: 6s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-timing-function:linear;
   -moz-animation-name:rotateSun;
   -moz-animation-duration: 10s;
   -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   -moz-animation-timing-function:linear;
   -webkit-animation-name:rotateSun;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7em #FFFF4D, 0 0 0.5em #FFFF4D, 0 0 0.3em #FFFF4D;
    float: left;
       }

  @keyframes rotateSun{
    from {background-position-x:1px;}
    to {background-position-x:1011px;}
        }


 @-o-keyframes rotateSun{
   from{background-position-x:1px;}
   to{background-position-x:1011px;}
       }

 @-moz-keyframes rotateSun{
   from {background-position-x:1px;}
   to {background-position-x:1011px;}
       }

@-webkit-keyframes rotateSun{
  from {background-position-x: 0px;}
  to {background-position-x:1010px;}
      }
```

So, it works pefectly in Safari, there's little freezing in Chrome but it's okay. My animation is completely dead in Opera and Firefox. Any idea?

http://www.astrogastro.byethost24.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard `background-position-x` property (and in particular Firefox doesn't have support for that non-standard feature).

Comment: Thank you! I corrected my code like this and it work's! @-moz-keyframes rotateSun{
 from {background-position:1px;}
 to {background-position:1011px;}
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix your @keyframes as well as your animation...